# Search Procedure resource by nullable date

Tags: hl7-fhir

Im looking at the [documentation](http://hl7.org/fhir/2016sep/procedure.html) for FHIR v1.6 Procedure and it looks like its possible to search by date.

My scenario is this:

- My Procedure's can have a `performedDatetime` value (for complete procedures) i.e. status=completed
- Or my Procedure can have a status of in-progress, in which case it will not have a defined `performedDatetime` value.

I know how to sort these procedures by `performedDatetime` using:

```
https://{{baseUrl}}/fhir/Procedure?_sort:desc=date
```

But is it possible to search for those procedures that dont have a `performedDateTime`?

I have been trying it this way:

```
https://{{baseUrl}}/fhir/Procedure?date:missing=false
```

But this still returns all results.

```
https://{{baseUrl}}/fhir/Procedure?date=NULL
```

Throws an error on the server.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://{{baseUrl}}/fhir/Procedure?date:missing=false
```

that's the right URL and it should work - guess you're going to have to report a bug on the server (may it not be mine!)

Comment: Thanks Grahame, so Im not going mad after all and there most likely is a bug on the server?

Comment: Okay, so I discovered something interesting here, on the server, incomplete Procedures have only a start datetime under performedDatetimePeriod, removing this allows me to filter the procedures correctly using https://{{baseUrl}}/fhir/Procedure?date:missing=false. Why does it also check on start datetime instead of just PerformedDatetime?